# Make all text of a given face invisible

Tags: faces, minor-mode, text-properties

Is there a straightforward way to make all text with a given face invisible? I don't believe I can make invisibility be intrinsic to the face, but can I perhaps specify a minor mode that makes sure all appropriate text is invisible?

By "invisible" here I mean the text works as if you'd set the invisible property, so the text in question doesn't even take up an horizontal space.

Comment: Yes, set the **:foreground** of the applicable face to be the same color as the `'default` **:background**.

Comment: Thanks @lawlist, but I mean invisible in the Emacs sense, in which the text in question doesn't even take up any space on the screen. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: You can write font-lock rules to apply any property, including `:invisible`. Instead of a plain face name, you can use a code block, which should return the name of the face to apply. This code block can contain side effects, like `(set-property ...)`. Also, you will need to include `:invisible` in `font-lock-extra-managed-props`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's a simple demonstration of @Lindydancer's technique, which in this case turns the whole buffer invisible.

```
(defun my-mode () "my-mode" (interactive)
  (kill-all-local-variables)
  (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
  (setq font-lock-defaults  '(my-mode-font-lock-keywords t)))

(defvar my-mode-font-lock-keywords nil 
  "Keywords/Regexp for fontlocking of my-mode")

(setq my-mode-font-lock-keywords
      (list
       '(".*" 0
         (progn (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) 
                                     (match-end 0) 
                                     '(invisible t))
                'bold))))

(add-to-list 'font-lock-extra-managed-props 'invisible)
```

Comment: Spot on! Yes, it should be `'invisible` since that is the property Emacs use to hide text. the `:xxx` form is used to specify face properties (I got them mixed up).