# How to match the URL component from a markdown link?

Tags: regular-expressions, url

I've been trying to hide the URL component of the markdown links in my buffer.

I could select the markdown links using

```
"\\(\\[.+\\]\\)\\((.+)\\)"
```

However, I just want to capture the second half (the URL component) of the links and fade them away in the buffer.

I have tried every possible documentation available but with no avail. Please help.

Comment: You should add `?` to your reqular expressions to avoid greedy matching, i.e., "\\(\\[.+?\\]\\)\\((.+?)\\)".

Comment: To capture the second half of the re just use the right subexpressions, such as `(match-beginning 1)` and `(match-end 1)`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, could you please provide one example?

Comment: It does not seem to identify the sub-expressions, I tried `\(\[.+?\]\)\((.+?)\)(match-end 1)`

Answer (score 1):

The following minimal example code shows how to hide the urls in md-files:

```el
(defun md-hide-urls ()
  "Hide all urls in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\(\\[.+\\]\\)\\((.+)\\)" nil t)
    (put-text-property (match-beginning 2) (match-end 2) 'invisible t)))
```

Regular expression search via lisp is described in [Section 33.4 of the emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Search.html).
How to make text invisible is described in [Section 37.6 of the emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Invisible-Text.html). You find informations on accessing match strings in [Section 37.6.2 of the emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html#Simple-Match-Data).

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking `(highlight-regexp <reg-exp> <face>)`. I highly doubt I could use it there.

Comment: @myTerminal AFAIK there is no face having the same effect as the `invisibility` text property. See also: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/make-all-text-of-a-given-face-invisible